# Unity3D on iOS, inspecting the device camera image in Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity/iOS app that captures the user's photo and displays it in the 3D environment. Now I'd like to leverage `CIFaceFeature` to find eye positions, which requires accessing the native (Objective-C) layer. My flow looks like:

Unity -> `WebCamTexture` (encode and send image to native -- **this is SLOW**)

Obj-C -> `CIFaceFeature` (find eye coords)

Unity -> Display eye positions

I've got a working prototype, but it's slow because I'm capturing the image in Unity (WebCamTexture) and then sending it to Obj-C to do the FaceFeature detection. It seems like there should be a way to simply ask my Obj-C class to "inspect the active camera". This would have to be much, much faster than encoding and passing an image.

So my question, in a nutshell:

- Can I query in Obj-C 'is there a camera currently capturing?'
- If so, how do I 'snapshot' the image from that currently running session?

Thanks!

Comment: how did you manage to convert the Color[] array in unity to a ObjC structure and how slow is it? Thanks

Comment: @MobileCushion This was awhile back now, so I'm not entirely sure I recall. I'm believe we converted it to a bytearray for piping to obj-C, then reconstructed it as a UIImage (maybe a CGImage?) on the native side. Slow here means maybe a second or so...way too slow for live eye detection, but passably acceptable for detection after the user snapped a picture (which is what we ended up doing).

Answer (score 2):

You can access the Camera's preview capture stream by changing CameraCapture.mm in unity.

I suggest that you have a look at some existing plugin called Camera Capture for an example of how additional camera I/O functionality can be added to the capture session / "capture pipeline".

To set you off in the right direction. have a look at the function initCapture in CameraCapture.mm :

```
- (bool)initCapture:(AVCaptureDevice*)device width:(int)w height:(int)h fps:(float)fps
```

Here you will be able to add to the capture session.

And then you should have a look at the code sample provided by Apple on Facial Recognition :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Unity 3D allows execution of native code. In the scripting reference, look for native plugins. In this way you can display a native iOS view (with the camera view, possibly hidden depending on your requirements) and run Objective C code. Then return the results of eye detection to Unity if you need it in a 3D view.

Comment: matt, I appreciate the answer, but I don't think you've really addressed the question. I'm already executing native Obj-C (as I indicated in my post). I know how to capture camera data in Obj-C OR Unity. My problem is that I want to capture and manipulate image data from the camera on the native side while simultaneously displaying it in Unity. (If you know a way to capture from the camera on the native-side and then send that data back to Unity in an efficient way, that would probably do the trick.)